# How to use a common method across all projects without having to pass the namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, localization, resx

I am working on localization of texts across all the 5 projects which together forms the product.

`Localization:` So If user is from USA, they will see the product in `en-US`, if they are from China they will see the text in `ch-CH`.

And  I am stuck at below stuff.

Each project will have its **OWN** bucket of Resx file (file where I am keeping for translations).

```
Project A - en-US.resx file
            cn-CH.resx file
Project B - en-US.resx file
            ch-CH.resx file
Project C - en-US.resx file
            ch-CH.resx file
.
.
.
```

Now I have a Project `Common` which gets referenced by all the projects.
So What I wrote a `singleton` class in `Common`

```
public sealed class Translation 
{
    private static readonly Translation translation = new Translation();

    public static Translation GetTranslation { get { return translation; } }
    private Translation() { }
    static Translation() { }

    public string GetTranslatedMessage(string key, CultureInfo culture, string message, string namespace)
    {
            var rm = new ResourceManager("namespace", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            message = rm.GetString(key, culture);
            return message;
    }
}
```

So far so good, As you can see I am using **namespace** as `4th parameter` with `resource manager` so that I can look for the translation in the right project bucket , I just do something like below:

```
Translation.Translate(key, culture, message, namespace) // singleton class taking in the namespace to find the right bucket
```

*And it works fine.*

**Question/Problem**: But from every project I need to pass the namespace, I mean where ever I call I need to pass the namespace. I am wondering is there any way, I can implicitly tell which bucket each project needs to look into. Can I use Abstract or 2 singleton classes, factory may be?, or something like that. I am newbie so I am not familiar on how to tackle this issue. I just don't want to pass namespace in every call.

*WorkAround:* I can repeat this same singleton code in each project and get the stuff working, but then I will be repeating same singleton code in each project/

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a hack-y solution, and your various namespaced files are in folders named after the namespace, you could use the `CallerFilePathAttribute` and split the namespace out of the path.  It does seem fragile:

Look up [C# Caller Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information).  The sample they show is:

```
public void DoProcessing()  
{  
    TraceMessage("Something happened.");  
}  

public void TraceMessage(string message,  
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",  
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",  
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)  
{  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("message: " + message);  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("member name: " + memberName);  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source file path: " + sourceFilePath);  
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("source line number: " + sourceLineNumber);  
}  

// Sample Output:  
//  message: Something happened.  
//  member name: DoProcessing  
//  source file path: c:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CallerInfoCS\CallerInfoCS\Form1.cs  
//  source line number: 31
```

Then take what they have labeled as `source file path` and play path games to get the namespace.  Parameters using these attributes are always optional (typically with they defaults set to default(T)).  The compiler injects the value, the caller should not.

Comment: Sir, is my problem that complicated, can't I use some standard pattern, abstract and all.. Just saying.. Please guide me. or factory, but then with singleton and factory?! not sure.